# How does exploration work in OpenAI Baselines?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, baseline

I'm starting to play around with https://github.com/openai/baselines/, specifically the deepq algorithm. I wanted to do my own analysis of the parameters passed into the deepq.learn method.

The method has two parameters related to exploration - `exploration_fraction` and `exploration_final_eps`.

The way I understand it - `exploration_fraction` determines how much of the training time does the algorithm spend exploring, and `exploration_final_eps` drives the probability of taking a random action each time explores. So - the number of random actions taken for the sake of exploring is a product of `exploration_fraction` and `exploration_final_eps`. Is that correct?

Can someone provide an explanation (in layman terms) of how the algorithm explores, based on these two parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is almost correct. The probability `p` of taking a random action (i.e., an exploratory action) is a number that often starts high and decreases over time. This makes sense because at the beginning of the learning stage the learning policy is still useless, but it gets better as the learning progresses.

Taking that into account, `exploration_fraction` and `exploration_final_eps` are the parameters that control how probability `p` decreases over time. When you explore the code in the [repo](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/deepq/deepq.py#L230), you find the following lines:

```
# Create the schedule for exploration starting from 1.
exploration = LinearSchedule(schedule_timesteps=int(exploration_fraction * total_timesteps),
                             initial_p=1.0,
                             final_p=exploration_final_eps)
```

Here it's easier to understand the meaning of `exploration_fraction` and `exploration_final_eps`:

- `exploration_fraction` determines for how long (in timesteps) `p` is decreasing. Notice that in this case `p=1` initially, but this initial value may vary.
- `exploration_final_eps` determines the minimum value of `p`. Once the probability has decreased during the period indicated by `exploration_fraction`, `p` will remain fix with a value equal to `exploration_final_eps`.

Sometimes `p` decreaes linearly, such as in the case of [`LinearSchedule`](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/9ee399f5b20cd70ac0a871927a6cf043b478193f/baselines/common/schedules.py#L76), but other ways are also possible.